# Proving $A+A'B=A+B$ without truth tables

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can I prove the Boolean algebraic rule
$$A+A'B=A+B$$
without using a truth table?

With the truth table, it is easy to see that the two are equal, but how can I prove it using lesser Boolean identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the distributivity of $\lor$ (sum) over $\land$ (product), which is unique to Boolean algebra:
$$A+A'B=(A+A')(A+B)=A+B$$

Comment: Expand: $(A + A')(A + B) = AA + AB + A'A + A'B = A + AB + A'A + A'B = A(1 + B) +0 + A'B = A + A'B$